# Ocaml unbound type constructor with module

Tags: types, constructor, module, ocaml

I'm working on this and i'm pretty sure while i was writing it the error din't show up. Now it does and i don't know why and how to solve it, i've searched for long but nothing.
it gives Unbound type constructor env on the last line
thanks everyone for feedback

```
module type ENV =
sig
type 't env
val emptyenv : 't -> 't env
val bind : 't env * string * 't -> 't env
val bindlist : 't env * (string list) * ('t list)-> 't env
val applyenv : 't env * string -> 't
exception WrongBindlist
end

module Funenv:ENV =
struct
type 't env = string -> 't
exception WrongBindlist
let emptyenv(x) = function (y: string) -> x
(* x: valore default *)
let applyenv(x,y) = x y
let bind(r, l, e) =
function lu -> if lu = l then e else applyenv(r,lu)
let rec bindlist(r, il, el) = match (il,el) with
| ([],[]) -> r
| i::il1, e::el1 -> bindlist (bind(r, i, e), il1, el1)
| _ -> raise WrongBindlist
end

module Listenv:ENV =
struct
type 't env = (string * 't) list
exception WrongBindlist
let emptyenv(x) = [("", x)]
let rec applyenv(x,y) = match x with
| [(_, e)] -> e
| (i1, e1) :: x1 -> if y = i1 then e1
else applyenv(x1, y)
| [] -> failwith("wrong env")
let bind(r, l, e) = (l, e) :: r
let rec bindlist(r, il, el) = match (il, el) with
| ([],[]) -> r
| i::il1, e::el1 -> bindlist (bind(r, i, e), il1, el1)
| _ -> raise WrongBindlist
end

type ide = string


type exp = Eint of int
| Ebool of bool

type eval = Int of int
| Bool of bool
| Unbound
| Funval of efun
and efun = exp * eval env
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who do you expect `env` to be on this last line?
`env` is not some type constructor that you have in scope, but a type constructor that belongs to an `ENV` module.

You could make the definition of `exp` and `efun` in one of theses modules or use `Listenv.env` for instance.

With the following, it compiles:

```
type eval = Int of int
| Bool of bool
| Unbound
| Funval of efun
and efun = exp * eval Listenv.env
```

---

Another solution, and that might have been what you were doing, is to put this definition directly in the signature:

```
module type ENV =
  sig
    type 't env
    val emptyenv : 't -> 't env
    val bind : 't env * string * 't -> 't env
    val bindlist : 't env * string list * 't list -> 't env
    val applyenv : 't env * string -> 't

    type ide  = string
    type exp  = Eint of int | Ebool of bool
    type eval = Int of int | Bool of bool | Unbound | Funval of efun
    and  efun = exp * eval env

    exception WrongBindlist
  end
```

But then, you have to provide them again in `Listenv` and `Funenv`.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but it's strange. Is there any good reason for not working now but working before? it compiled even though there was no Listenenv. before, i'm sure

Comment: Maybe you put this definition directly into the signature (I will edit my answer).